# Exception thrown multiple times in computed signals (angular)

Tags: angular, typescript, exception, signals

I'm using signals in an Angular application.

I'm using a `computed` signal like this, I'm voluntarily throwing an exception to test what happens when an exception is being thrown within a "computed" signals, my real code is much more complex.

```js
  public test: Signal<string> = computed(() => {
    throw new Error(`Testing throwing exception`);
    return 'foo';
  });
```

```html
  <p>{{ test() }}</p>
```

When I look at the console, I see the exception being thrown multiple times (at least 15 times)
[image: exception in console]

I'm using bugsnag to report unexpected exceptions and it is reported to bugsnag many times instead of one.

One solution I find is to add a try catch within my computed function and manually report to bugsnag like this:

```js
  public test: Signal<string> = computed(() => {
    try {
      throw new Error(`Testing throwing exception`);
      return 'foo';
    } catch (error) {
      Bugsnag.notify(error as NotifiableError);
      return '';
    }
  });
```

**But is there a better way to handle this use case ? I'm guessing it's quite common to want to handle exceptions within a "computed signal"**

Comment: In my understanding, and by documentation "A computed signal derives its value from other signals." Possibly, behavior is unpredictable otherwise. My guess, predicate function is called on every changeDetection cycle, and throwing errors one by one.